# Is there a way to sort each odd and even object in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to append every even object on the left side of a vertical line, and every odd object on the right side. I am not sure how I can achieve this.
Sample of the JSON, (This is just dummy data for now) (url)

```
[{
        "Year": 2010,
        "Title": "Cadillac",
        "Description": "Escalade ESV"
    },
    {
        "Year": 1998,
        "Title": "Volvo",
        "Description": "V70"
    },
    {
        "Year": 1992,
        "Title": "Toyota",
        "Description": "Camry"
    },
    {
        "Year": 2012,
        "Title": "Ford",
        "Description": "Explorer"
    }]
```

Heres my code:

```
fetch(url)
.then(result => {
  return result.json();
})
.then (data =>{
  console.log(data);
  data.forEach( (point) => {
      const appendToHtml =  `
      <div class="container left">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>${point.Title}</h2>
                <p>${point.Description}</p>
                <p>${point.Year}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container right">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>${point.Title}</h2>
                <p>${point.Description}</p>
                <p>${point.Year}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            `;
      $(".timeline").append(appendToHtml);
    });
  })
```

The issue is it append on the left AND the right.
[Click here for an image of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG8Ks.png)
I need to alternate
for example
Cadillac on the left, Volva on the right etc...
I cant seem to figure out what to do..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the odd or even of car index and based on that apply class `left` and `right`.

```
data.forEach( (point, index) => {
  const isOdd = index % 2;
  const appendToHtml =  `
  <div class="container ${isOdd ? 'right' : 'left' }">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>${point.Title}</h2>
            <p>${point.Description}</p>
            <p>${point.Year}</p>
        </div>
    </div>`;
  $(".timeline").append(appendToHtml);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Didnt know you could use % like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
fetch(url)
.then(result => {
  return result.json();
})
.then (data =>{
  console.log(data);
  data.forEach( (point, i) => {
      const appendToHtml =  `
      <div class=`container ${i%2 === 0 ? "right" : "left" }`>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>${point.Title}</h2>
                <p>${point.Description}</p>
                <p>${point.Year}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            `;
      $(".timeline").append(appendToHtml);
    });
  })
```

Use template literal for finding odd even using mod function